# Why does spring nativeQuery with pagination throw a SQLGrammarException?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, nativequery

I am trying to run the following Query in Spring 4.2.4:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.TYPE_NUMBER ASC) AS RN, i.* FROM Item i) AS g WHERE RN between ?#{ #pageable.offset} and ?#{#pageable.offset + #pageable.pageSize}",
        countQuery="SELECT count(i.ID) FROM Item i",
    nativeQuery = true)
Page<Item> getItems(Pageable pageable);
```

This code follows the example showed here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java#L539

This results in a SQLGrammarException:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1909) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:191) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

This is `caused` by:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ','.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:?]...
```

I have tried running the same native query without Pagination and it will run without any errors. The query looks like this:

```
  @Query(value="SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.TYPE_NUMBER ASC) AS RN, i.* FROM Item i) AS g WHERE RN between 0 and 50",
        nativeQuery = true)
    List<Item> getItems();
```

Is this a limitation of spring data or am I missing something here?

Comment: Is there a `cause` to that `SQLGrammarException`?

Comment: Yes, here's the cause: `Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ','.`  This only occurs when it's run using Pageable object.

Comment: Enable the sql log to see the executed sql http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/hibernate/3548/enable-disable-sql-log#t=201611260820368460879

Comment: @DanielKäfer Thanks. I enabled SQL debug on hibernate, and found the problem was with the dynamic sorting of Pageable object:   `PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 25, Sort.Direction.ASC, "itemCategory");`  With the dynamic sorting parameters on pageable object Hibernate generates `SELECT top 25 * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.TYPE_NUMBER ASC) AS RN, i.* FROM Item i) AS g WHERE RN between ? and ?, i.itemCategory asc`  The error being pretty obvious here. Do you know of a way to use the sorting parameters of pageable with native query?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bug in spring data. Spring data append `, i.itemCategory asc` if the query contains `ORDER BY`. In the other case spring data adds `ORDER BY i.itemCategory asc`. As workaround you can add `ORDER BY 1=1` to the query.

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.TYPE_NUMBER ASC) AS RN, i.* FROM Item i) AS g WHERE RN between ?#{ #pageable.offset} and ?#{#pageable.offset + #pageable.pageSize}, ORDER BY 1=1",
        countQuery="SELECT count(i.ID) FROM Item i",
    nativeQuery = true)
Page<Item> getItems(Pageable pageable);
```